# Change binary search tree to balance

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have just learnt how to create a binary search data structure, which is going to be used to store thousands of words from a dictionary. The problem that I am getting is that it is taking a long time to count add and remove data. Usually 199263ms or 200 seconds for 100000 words to count. I was told that having a tree that can self balance will improve the efficiency and make the operations faster.

My question is how can I make my tree auto balance so to make it efficient. I have made slight improvements by eliminating duplicate words to make the height of the tree to be shorter.

If someone can give me advice on how i can make the tree efficient and how I can implement balancing tree in java will be helpful.

Comment: I see two main approaches to this: A. self balance each time an element is added, or B. remake the tree as balanced every so often

Comment: See [Self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).  It can be quite complicated.

Comment: Have any of the answers so far answered your question? If so, please accept the most helpful answer.

Comment: A java TreeSet or TreeMap already uses a binary [**AVL tree**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) which is balanced.

Comment: One problem for normal binary trees, is: when written in order to a file the next time reading from such an ordered file will actually create list, a tree with only left or right branches.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into red/black trees, which are self balancing. The nodes store a color in addition to an element, and every time the tree is modified, you rebalance the tree so that it meets the properties of a red/black tree:

(From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree):)

> 1. Each node is either red or black.
> 2. The root is black.
> 3. All leaves (NIL) are black.
> 4. If a node is red, then both its children are black.
> 5. Every path from a given node to any of its descendant NIL nodes
>    contains the same number of black nodes.

To get started implementing a red black tree, I recommend looking at [this example implementation](https://github.com/Arsenalist/Red-Black-Tree-Java-Implementation/blob/master/src/RedBlackTree.java) on github, and reading [this explanation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/red-black-tree-set-1-introduction-2/) of red black trees.

Answer (score 0):

To balance a binary tree, it may be easier to just construct a new one, adding elements in a better order

```
BinaryTree balance(BinaryTree tree)
{
    BinaryTree out = new BinaryTree();
    String[] values = tree.toArray(); //a sorted array
    for(int i = Integer.highestOneBit(values.length); i > 0; i >>= 1)
        for(int j = i; j <= values.length; j += i)
            out.add(values[j - 1]);
    return out;
}
```

By extension of this, if the words read in do not need to be put into a tree and sorted right away, [`Arrays.sort(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-) is likely to be faster

```
List<String> wordList = new LinkedList<String>();
BufferedReader reader = [...];
for(String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine())
    wordList.add(line);
String[] words = wordList.toArray(new String[0]);
Arrays.sort(words);
BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
for(int i = Integer.highestOneBit(words.length); i > 0; i >>= 1)
    for(int j = i; j <= words.length; j += i)
        out.add(words[j - 1]);
```

Depending on what you're actually using this data for (just a lookup table?) it may be faster to use a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instead

```
Set<String> dict = new HashSet<String>();
BufferedReader reader = [...];
for(String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine())
    dict.add(line);
```